# How to get a row by column name

Tags: c#, odbc, text-driver

I am trying to get a column value by name instead of by ordinal. Here is the code I already have:

```
SELECT trim([Workitem Id]) as [Workitem Id1] from 1.csv
```

above is the query

```
rrm.id = oDR["Workitem Id"] == DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : oDR["Workitem Id"];
```

When I run this query I get too few parameters expected error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column name is actually `Workitem Id1` is it not?

Comment: The column name is: Workitem Id

Comment: @Luke101 But you aliased it as `Workitem Id1`, so you can't access it by the original column name.

Comment: Wow..I didnt see that. I fixed but it is still returning the same error.

Comment: Can you loop through the column names in your data reader to make sure you have the column names correct?

Comment: OMG..I can't believe it. I just had the query pointing to the wrong file. thanks for your time for giving me a hint at the problem.